# Booting over the LAN using uboot

Tags: kernel, dhcp, initramfs, u-boot, tftp

I am trying to boot my [beaglebone](http://beagleboard.org/bone) over the LAN. I am able to download the Kernel uImage from the TFTP server. Here is what I did -

```
U-Boot SPL 2011.09-00053-gb423c52 (Aug 10 2012 - 11:26:55)
Texas Instruments Revision detection unimplemented
No daughter card present
OMAP SD/MMC: 0
reading u-boot.img
reading u-boot.img


U-Boot 2011.09-00053-gb423c52 (Aug 10 2012 - 11:26:55)

I2C:   ready
DRAM:  256 MiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled
No daughter card present
NAND:  HW ECC Hamming Code selected
No NAND device found!!!
0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
*** Warning - readenv() failed, using default environment

Net:   cpsw
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
U-Boot# dhcp
link up on port 0, speed 100, full duplex
BOOTP broadcast 1
BOOTP broadcast 2
DHCP client bound to address 192.1.1.101
Using cpsw device
TFTP from server 192.1.1.254; our IP address is 192.1.1.101
Filename 'uImage-BBone'.
Load address: 0x82000000
Loading: #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         ################################
done
Bytes transferred = 3319832 (32a818 hex)
U-Boot# bootm
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
   Image Name:   Angstrom/3.2.28/beaglebone
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3319768 Bytes = 3.2 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

1. I did not specify the load address of 0x82000000. Uboot seem to have chosen this all by itself. Does it matter where the uImage is downloaded to?
2. Is the second load address that I see on the console after giving the `bootm` command (Load Address: 80008000 & Entry Point:  80008000) a standard address? Does the kernel image have to be located at a specific location in memory?
3. I am stuck after this. There is no ramdisk. How do I load a ramdisk? And how do I tell the kernel to look for it at a specific memory location? The image I am using was downloaded from [here](http://downloads.angstrom-distribution.org/demo/beaglebone/). Do I need to create a new image to be able to use the ramdisk? Can I use a NFS mount at this point of time? When can I mount an NFS partition as the root file system?

Comment: IIRC, uImages are some sort of container file format that can contain a kernel and initrd and metadata about where they should be loaded. How and where to load them could be platform specific. And you specify it at the time of making the uImage.