# Can't Flash Image onto Arduino Yun Shield using Uboot or TFTP

Tags: boot, openwrt, tftp, arduino

*Note:* This question was originally asked on Arduino Stack exchange, but closed as off-topic because it's an OpenWRT issue.

I have a Geeetech Iduino Yun Shield. I accidentally flashed [the wrong firmware image](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunSysupgrade) (not the sysupgrade) to the board. I then tried using the [Yun UBoot Reflash](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunUBootReflash) method. However, when I open the console monitor from the IDE and restart/reboot the board, I do not get the UBoot prompt. I have attempted to run it at least ten times without receiving any console/serial output.

The shield is running on a Leonardo base board.

Is there anything I can do to load the correct firmware onto the shield and get it operational or is it truly bricked? If it's bricked, is it possible to obtain a new Atheros AR9331 module to replace the existing one or should I buy a new Yun?

I have tried to get the shield to do an FTP boot, [as detailed here by Majenko](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/fixing-the-dragino-yun-board/). I get to the stage where I get the `dr_boot>` prompt. However, when I type in `tftpboot 0x81000000 dragino2-yun-common-v2.0.6-kernel.bin`, I get no feedback; it just sits there indefinitely (unless I interrupt the process). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

*Note:* [This question, currently unanswered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60115/booting-over-the-lan-using-uboot?rq=1) may be related; I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems more a related hw than Unix problem. The board may be toast.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to diagnose if the board (or which part thereof) is toast? Should I ask in EE?